# What is the location of Dr. Louise Banks's house?

Tags: real-location, arrival

What is the real-world location of the house used as Dr. Louise Banks's home in the movie?

[image]

Comment: Do you mean to ask where it's meant to be in the film, or where the location filming was actually done?

Comment: @MikeScott - A good answer addresses both :-)

Comment: i mean where is the house in the real world.

Comment: @linzhu - And now you have your answer :-) Go take us a better picture...

Answer (score 19):

### In-universe location.

The [script](http://www.paramountguilds.com/pdf/arrival.pdf) and film are intentionally vague on the subject. Louise appears to be an American national (and her students have American accents) which would imply that she lives in America *somewhere* but there aren't any obvious markers. Her house is simply described as "***Lake House***", the university is simply "***University Classroom***".

Note that her university's name isn't shown and the hospital where she has her daughter is described as "***Mercy Hill Hospital***", a fictional place. The numberplates in the university car park don't conform to any US or Canadian plate style.

### Source material

No help here. Chiang's [short story](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Story_of_Your_Life) doesn't contain any location markers, nor any mention of Louise's house.

### Real-world location

The interior shots for the film were shot in and around [Saint-Fabien](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=Saint-Fabien%20quebec&espv=2&biw=1360&bih=638&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjiy-q7j-fRAhXKKMAKHdBpCdoQ_AUIBygC#imgrc=GanZFM7Z7T_iWM%3A) in Quebec. [This interview](https://britishcinematographer.co.uk/bradford-young-asc-arrival/) (and the [answer below](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/151404/20774)) confirm that the house was an actual location, rather than a set. The exterior driveway shot was filmed in L'Île-Cadieux, Québec, as were the interior shots of her house looking out over the [Lake of Two Mountains](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lake_of_Two_Mountains)

For the record, the exterior (university) shots were filmed at the Université de Montréal, Quebec.

Answer (score 13):

[Here is the Streetview of the house](https://www.google.com.br/maps/@45.429546,-74.0289504,3a,75y,344.68h,86.95t/data=!3m6!1e1!3m4!1sE_tspuFkLPDx2AXw6xHDig!2e0!7i13312!8i6656!6m1!1e1). It's in L'Île-Cadieux, Québec.

[image]
[image]

**Film**:

[image]

It would appear that the interior was also used. Note that the side window also points toward a small inlet, visible in the overhead view.
[image]

Comment: @Valorum why not add both?

Comment: @Gallifreyan - I've managed to match the interior shots with the overhead view.

Comment: @Valorum that's the summary of my life on SE - it starts with an innocent edit, then attempt to improve, and then there's nothing left of the original post and I've spent two hours. But good job, sir!

Comment: @Gallifreyan - Andrei still deserved the credit. I've taken images from the link he provided.